# Externally add a Variable to a model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have an existing TensorFlow model, and I want to add a new "parameter" (a `tf.Variable`) to the model's list of parameters (such that it's trainable) and add it externally to the model's list of parameters / computational graph.

One approach that I tried, is to append the new parameters to the model's list of trainable weights, something like this (here `new_parameter` is a `tf.Variable`) -

```
model.layers[-1].trainable_weights.extend([new_parameter])
model.compile(....)
```

But I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it. In PyTorch, we have `nn.Parameter` instead of `tf.Variable`, and we have [`register_parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter) using which we can register tensors as new parameter's to the model's list of parameters. Is there any equivalent of `register_parameter` in TensorFlow? Or some other way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I get what you are trying to accomplish, but this article might help you: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models

Comment: @Marcus Thank you for the reference, I looked into it. I'm actually looking for a TensorFlow alternative for the functionality provided by PyTorch's `register_parameter` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by custom dense layer too ‼️

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)   

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(15):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(18):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Function
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, num_add):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.num_add = num_add
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.add( inputs, self.num_add )
        temp = tf.matmul(temp, self.kernel)
        return temp

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
list_file = tf.cast( list_file, dtype=tf.int64 )
list_file = tf.constant( list_file, shape=(33, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64)
list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.int64 )
list_label = tf.constant( list_label, shape=(33, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( list_file, list_label ))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
])

layer = MyDenseLayer(10, 5)

model.add(layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""   
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=50 )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)


plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.show()
plt.close()

input("...")
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 normalization (Normalizatio  (None, 32, 32, 4)        0
 n)

 normalization_1 (Normalizat  (None, 32, 32, 4)        0
 ion)

 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 30, 30, 32)        1184

 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 15, 15, 32)       0
 )

 dense (Dense)               (None, 15, 15, 128)       4224

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 128, 225)          0

 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 128, 192)         247296
 l)

 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectio  (None, 192)              221952
 nal)

 my_dense_layer (MyDenseLaye  (None, 10)               1920
 r) ***  custom layer added

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 10)                0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 192)               2112

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1930

=================================================================
Total params: 480,618
Trainable params: 480,618
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Is this answer relevant to the question I posted? I went through the whole code, but couldn't find the part where you have registered new parameters to the model, or anything else relevant to the question. Thanks for the answer, but kindly check once if you answered a different question by chance. A clarification would be helpful. Thank you!